# Does Stack Overflow still use recaptcha? And if so what version does it use?

Tags: support, captcha

I noticed I don't see it on the site anymore, so I just wanted to know whether it's still used.

Comment: Congratulations, you've been upgraded to *human* and do not require any more CAPTCHAs.

Comment: @deceze The story of how I turned from a human into a robot: ...must click car... must click sign.... car... sign... car... sign....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We currently use reCAPTCHA v2 - you can view it here: https://stackoverflow.com/captcha